# A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I'm struggling with a problem using EntityFrmework 6.2 async method into winform application.
We use custom class in order to manage sync or async EntityFrmework access based on single activity setup. When we use sync access all works fine. When we use async call, we run into this issue:A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
We have already read a lot of post regarding this issue but none of them could help us to solve our problem.

We know the problem is related to call async method from the sync one, unfortunatelly we could not convert calling method from sync to async.
We have extracted from our project two methods in order to demonstrate described behaviour

```
public void AddLoadingRequest(Func<Task> fnAsync, Action fnSync, Action bsa)
{
    try
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(async () => await DoDataSource(fnAsync, fnSync, bsa));
        _lstTask.Add(task);
        if (task.IsFaulted)
            throw task.Exception;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error {ex.Message}");
    }
}

protected async Task DoDataSource(Func<Task> fnAsync, Action fnSync, Action bsa)
{
    try
    {
        if (_bLoadingFKTableAsync == true)
            await fnAsync();
        else
            fnSync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Loading Error");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Calling method:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NWContext wContext = new NWContext();
    Customers cust = wContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(w => w.CustomerID == "RATTC");
    BindingSource bsCustomer = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource bsOrders = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource bsCustomerDemographics = new BindingSource();
    bsCustomer.DataSource = cust;
    _bLoadingFKTableAsync = true;
    AddLoadingRequest(
            () => wContext.Entry(cust).Collection(typeof(Orders).Name).LoadAsync(),
            () => wContext.Entry(cust).Collection(typeof(Orders).Name).Load(),
            () =>
            {
                bsOrders.SuspendBinding();
                bsOrders.DataSource = cust.Orders;
                bsOrders.ResumeBinding();
            });
    AddLoadingRequest(
            () => wContext.Entry(cust).Collection(typeof(CustomerDemographics).Name).LoadAsync(),
            () => wContext.Entry(cust).Collection(typeof(CustomerDemographics).Name).Load(),
            () =>
            {
                bsCustomerDemographics.SuspendBinding();
                bsCustomerDemographics.DataSource = cust.CustomerDemographics;
                bsCustomerDemographics.ResumeBinding();
            });
}
```

We expect EntityFramework will load two child collection of object in async mode, while we have the error: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: So what is the question? You specifically make 2 calls to `AddLoadingRequest`, both of which starts an async operation using the same context. You don't (a)wait for the first to complete before you start the second one.

Comment: We are trying to call 'DoDataSource' async method  from AddLoadingRequest sync method; we have the reported error, because we could not change calling method AddLoadingRequest from sync to async. The question is: how could we call two or more async EF request from inside existing sync method?

Answer (score 4):

> The question is: how could we call two or more async EF request from inside existing sync method?

You need two or more database contexts. Each one can only have a single request going at a time.

On a side note, I strongly recommend that you change the method(s) to be `async`. Skipping the `await` like this is a way of doing "fire and forget", which has two main problems:

1. Your code cannot know when the operation has completed. Can I re-use this database context now that it's done doing that db operation? Can I safely exit the app knowing that all db updates have been applied? These are questions that cannot be answered with "fire and forget" code.
2. Your code cannot know whether the operation has succeeded. With "fire and forget", your code must just *assume* that it worked.

Comment: I was worried the only solution was to get more than one context. Thank you very much for your quick and exaustive response.

Comment: @FabioBorghi if this solved your problem, mark the answer as the solution.